# sending json from android device to asp.net web page

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am sending messages using JSON from Android to a webpage. My JSON format is:

```
{ "id":"123", "message" : "Hello World!" }
```

I want to send this message to the user that has the same id as in the json file **or** to all users in the case that id is equal to zero (id="0").

How can I do that using `asp.net` or `jQuery`?

Comment: Exactly what type of message you want to send ? Can you please give us a little more detail ?

Comment: @RahulSharma just the message itself. ex:"hello world"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a server cannot send information to a browser: it's always the browser which request the data to the server, and get a response from it.

However, there are several things that you can do. In modern browsers with a good support for HTML5 there are Web Sockets, you can use polling, or several other techniques.

However, the easiest way to do it is to use an existing implementation. And, in this case, there is one, called [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). I recommend you using this technology. [Here there are docs to learn to use it](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Other advantage of using SignalR is that it uses WebSockets if they are available, but, if they're not available, it uses some other technique, like polling, to be compatible with older browsers.

If you want to see what can be done with SignalR and how to do it, [here you have a very quick explanation](http://danielhindrikes.se/tag/websockets/).

By the way, you don't need to create the JSON messages. You simply send and receive JavaScript objects in the client side. I.e. you don't have to worry about serializing/deserializing the messages.

Comment: isn't SignalR just for broadcasting data?

Comment: I've added a last link show that you can see what can be done with SignalR. As you'll see, you can do broadcast, or send messages to individual users.